# UIWebView memory issue when include remote javascript file in script tag

Tags: javascript, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I have custom view containing 5  UIWebViews, each of which loading html string as follows:

```
NSString *htmlStr = @"<html> ....
....
//CSS code
....
<body>
....
//Contents to display ... might be mathematical expressions
....
<script>
....
//some javascript code
....
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src = "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>

</body>
</html>";
.
.
.
.
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlStr baseURL:nil];
```

Initially, I thought that UIWebView is not getting released event after remove custom view and setting it to nil. I've tried number of ways to release webview resources like :

```
webView.delegate = nil;
[webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
[webView stopLoading];
[webView removeFromSuperView];
webView = nil;

[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
```

and lot more.

Later, after debugging the code I found that issue lie in remote javascript I'm loading each time, which is increasing memory by 20-30 MB.
If I remove view and add another with different content its again increasing memory upto 50-60 MB. I try removing that remote src line from code and see increase in memory is just by 1-2 MB.

How can I fix this issue ?

1. If I predict, we have to cache response of javascript src for first time and use it whenever required. But how can this be possible with loadHTMLString (the string which is dynamically retrieved from db).
2. Is it possible to use both loadHTMLString and loadRequest for same & single webview, so that loadRequest for javascript src with cache policy would contain cached response ?
3. Is it possible to use cached response for webview loading HTML string ?

Any help would greatly appreciated, Thanks !

Comment: Just switched to WKWebview and all memory issue related to UIWebView has solved.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.